Пишет None, даже когда в таблице написано значение: SQLite, Python
Пишу своего бота в Telegram и сейчас делаю выбор языка пользователя при первом запуске. Переводы хранятся в файлах .json. По факту, в таблице изменения обновляются, но при этом в консоль всё равно выводит None, соответственно мое условие не выполняется и бот снова присылает сообщение с выбором языка.
# Обновление элемента в таблице по кнопке
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    global messages, file
    db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    if callback.data == 'EN':
        file = open("en.json", "r", encoding="utf-8")
        messages = json.load(file)
        cursor.execute(f"""UPDATE options SET language = 'en' WHERE id = {callback.message.chat.id}""")
        db.commit()
        start(callback.message)

# Команда /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS options(
        id integer UNIQUE,
        language text,
        game text,
        timer integer DEFAULT 10,
        percents integer DEFAULT 1
    )""")

    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT id FROM options WHERE id = {message.chat.id}""")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO options (id) VALUES ({message.chat.id})""")
        db.commit()

    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT language FROM options WHERE id = {message.chat.id}""")
    cursor.fetchone()
    db.commit()
    print(cursor.fetchone())
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        rus = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' English', callback_data='EN')
        eng = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' Русский', callback_data='RU')
        markup.row(rus, eng)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Choose a language\n Выберите язык", reply_markup=markup)
    elif cursor.fetchone() == 'en': #еще пробовал '(en,)' как обычно выводится в консоль
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, messages['Main'], parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=main_mark())


Вы зачем-то вызываете fetchone аж целых четыре раза. Если первый fetchone уже забрал первую и единственную строку, то второму, третьему и четвёртому fetchone закономерно будет уже нечего забирать и они будут вынуждены выдать None
